# How to implement this process ? React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend

I have user with two parameters (username, and user groups )

I have Page that's update my user by changing username and update groups
it looks like:
[image]

Problem is , I can't highlight groups , I need to choose to update .

```
const AddUser = props =>{
 
  let editing = false;
  let initialUsername = "";
  const[initialGroups, setInitialGroups] = useState([])


  useEffect(()=>{
    retrieveGroups();
    
  },[])

  const retrieveGroups = () => {
    BackendService.getAllGroups()
    .then(response => {
      setInitialGroups(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
  


  const[username, setUsername] = useState(initialUsername);
  const[groups, setGroups] = useState(initialGroups);
  const[submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);



  const onChangeUsername = e => {

    const username = e.target.value;
    setUsername(username);

  }

  const onChangeGroups = e => {
    console.log(e);
    setGroups(Array.from(e.currentTarget.selectedOptions, (v) => v.value));
  }
  const saveUser = () => {
    var data = {
      username: username,
      groups: groups,
      complited: false,
    }
    
    BackendService.editUser(
      props.location.state.currentUser.id,
      data)
      .then(response=>{
        setSubmitted(true);
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
      })
   )
  .catch(e=>{
    console.log(e);
  });

    }
  }
  
return(
  <Container>
    {submitted ? (
      <div>
        <h4>
          User Edited Successfully
        </h4>
        <Link to={"/users/"}></Link>
        Back to Users
      </div>
    ):(
      <Form>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3">
          <Form.Label>
            "Edit" User
          </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
          type="text"
          required
          value={username}
          placeholder="Enter username here"
          onChange={onChangeUsername}
          />
          <Form.Control
          as="select"
          multiple value={initialGroups}
          onChange={onChangeGroups}
          >
            {initialGroups.map(group => (
              <option key={group.id} value={group.id}>
                {group.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="info" onClick={saveUser}>
          "Edit" User
        </Button>
      </Form>
    )}

  </Container>
)
}
export default AddUser;
```

In this section I get all groups(initialGroups) I have in database:

```
 const[initialGroups, setInitialGroups] = useState([])
    
    
      useEffect(()=>{
        retrieveGroups();
        
      },[])
    
      const retrieveGroups = () => {
        BackendService.getAllGroups()
        .then(response => {
          setInitialGroups(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }
```

After I put InitialGroups in :

```
       <Form.Control
          as="select"
          multiple value={initialGroups}
          onChange={onChangeGroups}
          >
            {initialGroups.map(group => (
              <option key={group.id} value={group.id}>
                {group.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
```

And process  in :

```
const onChangeGroups = e => {
    console.log(e);
    setGroups(Array.from(e.currentTarget.selectedOptions, (v) => v.value));
  }
```

What I do wrong ? I can't highlight group I need to proces and update user

Comment: Hi @tarp20, can you help explain the question a bit more? Is the issue the selected groups are not showing as selected? Or that they are not being persisted when saving the user?

Comment: hi @DanielJ, yes I can't even select groups

Comment: Instead of: `value={initialGroups}`, please see if `value={groups}` makes any difference, at all. Also, please render from `groups` (instead of: `initialGroups.map`).

Comment: @jsN00b hi, when I changed to value={groups} i started to be able to select groups I  want. but if change to groups.map - all groups despaired

Comment: Okay, I think I've understood. In the `Array.from()` the callback only picks out the value. Try setting option like so: `<option key={group.id} name={group.name} value={group.id} >{group.name}</option>`. And, I'm hoping the `console.log(e)` should show the `name` as well. Then, in the callback we may try: `(v) => ({name: v.name, id: v.value});`

Comment: @jsN00b now after choosing one group , dissapiring all groups

Comment: Got it. Let us try more changes. 1) On the declaration: `const[groups, setGroups] = useState(initialGroups.map(x => ({...x, checked: false;})));`. 2) Within `onChangeGroups`,  please try: `setGroups(prev => {const curr = [...prev].map((ob, idx) => { const selectedValues = Array.from(e.currentTarget.selectedOptions, (v) => v.value); if (selectedValues.includes(ob.id)) { ob.checked = !prev[idx].checked; }; return ob; }); return curr; });` And add `selected={group.checked}` in `<option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to make the following suggestions:

- You don't need to use 'initialGroups' as a state variable. You already have a 'groups' variable which can receive an initial value.

```js
const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
```

- You can directly set the 'groups' variable once you retrieve the data.

```js
        BackendService.getAllGroups()
          .then(response => {
            setGroups(response.data);
        })
```

- You should pass 'groups' to the 'value' prop on the Form component, instead of 'initialGroups' (and then map over it).

```
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            multiple 
            value={groups}
            onChange={onChangeGroups}
          >
          {groups.map(group => (
            <option key={group.id} value={group.id}>
              {group.name}
            </option>
          ))}
          </Form.Control>
```

Hope this helps!